# How can I monitor and send a wet signal from my DAW to my conferencing software?

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces, daw, compression, live-sound

I purchased a Shure SM57 to use for conference calls. It is connected to an audio interface (RME Babyface original). I want to apply dynamic effects to it but the software that comes with the RME Babyface only allows me to apply EQ to the mic signal.

[image]

I guess this is by design, because a dynamic effects option is available to some of RME's other audio interfaces when they use Totalmix.

Unfortunately, Totalmix doesn't allow me to insert plugins into channels, so that's not an option, and I don't want to buy hardware.

I simply want to be able to send a wet signal to my conferencing software and monitor that wet signal in my headphones.

I thought about using ProTools and its AUX I/O option. However, that's not available in ProTools Intro, which is the free version of ProTools. I can't justify paying a monthly subscription for ProTools Artist just to be able to use the AUX I/O option.

Are there any other options out there that will make it possible to monitor and send a wet signal from a DAW to my conferencing software? If not, is there some other way I can achieve the goal?

Comment: What’s the conferencing software and what’s your OS? I have this working on a Mac with Zoom just using Zoom and my DAW with no other tools

Comment: I'm using Monterey (OSX). I regularly use Google Meets, Skype and Zoom. @ToddWilcox

Comment: With Zoom, if you enable high-fidelity audio mode it should create virtual IO that you can set your DAW or software to use as the input and/or output. So, for example, in Logic I set the output "interface" to "ZoomAudioDevice" and then share screen in Zoom with shared sound, choose stereo sound sharing, and when I hit play in Logic everyone on the Zoom call can hear the playback. You might do a web search or check Zoom docs on how to enable and use the Zoom Audio Device.